# Creating a bullet list in HTML

Tags: html

I'm simply trying to add a bulleted list in an ASP.NET aspx page.

I have the code as below on the aspx page... As you can see, there is no class being used on the ul tag...

```
 <ul type="circle">
                        <li>Upon receipt and inspection of the returned merchandise, credit will be issued based
                            on purchase price. Merchandise not originally purchased from xyz will be
                            credited at the current lowest market price.</li>
                        <li>All returns are subject to a handling fee.</li>
                        <li>It is recommended to allow 14 business days for a credit to be processed. Please
                            note, merchandise returned at the end of the month may not be processed in time
                            to be reflected on the current month’s statement.</li>
                        <li>Merchandise that is deemed as unacceptable per manufacturer’s policy will not be
                            credited and will be returned at the customer’s expense.</li>
                    </ul>
```

Below is the output. It's not putting any bullet points out. What am I doing wrong?

```
aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
cccccccc
dddddddd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might need to check your css

check for css that is saying

```
 ul, li { display:inline; AND list-style:none; OR float:left; }
```

markup for a unordered 'bullet' list is ( in case that is what you were asking ) ..

```
 <ul>
  <li>aaaaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbbbbbb</li>
  <li>ccccc</li>
  <li>dddddd</li>
  <li>eeeeee</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you do not need a class - see answer - this css declaration effects all ul's - check your css file ( find 'ul' or 'li')

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction by looking in the css file. I placed another class in the abbengine.css file and used that specific class on the list in question to force bullet points

Comment: glad you got sorted, and thanks, sorry my bad , just re read that I stated 'classes' - edited the answer

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you're using a CSS reset of some sort. Comment it out and try again, it should work.